# Yank plain text in Emacs?

Tags: windows, emacs, text-editing

**Using Windows 7 / 8, GNU Emacs 24.3.1**

I often yank text copied from browser or incoming email. Is there a way to yank/paste as plain text, leaving out special characters?

I tried Ditto and Puretext clipboard assistants, but they does not seem to work with Emacs kill-ring.

My current workaround is *paste into notepad* >> *select all* >> *copy* >> *yank into Emacs*, which is  a bit time consuming.

Comment: Emacs is a *text* editor, so it'll usually ignore the original font attributes, using only the text; the final format of the text will depend on your major mode. That being said, emacs is also highly extensible, so this can be due to some exotic major mode you've been using. Can you provide information on what major modes do you see these issues?

Comment: I am using org-mode, but testing I get the same message when trying to save (a new, non org-mode) buffer as ordinary text file: `These default coding systems were tried to encode text
in the buffer 'test.txt':
  (iso-latin-1-dos (88 . 9660) (1538 . 8211) (2432 . 8211))
However, each of them encountered characters it couldn't encode:
  iso-latin-1-dos cannot encode these: ▼ – –**`

Comment: Sometimes my emacs yank colorized text when I copy from a buffer with syntax highlight to one without it, but this is just a visual artifact; if I save the buffer, the file is a plain text file. I don't use emacs on Windows though.